# Display custom user name and password modal dialog with Plaid Link

Tags: javascript, plaid

I'm using Plaid Link with its *[custom integration](https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#step-2-custom-integration)* and so far I am able to pull the list of institutions. This is great because I don't have to hardcode the list of institutions and I can display a custom modal dialog for selection institutions.

Now the next step is to let the user enter their credentials so I get the `public_token` and `metadata` through the `onSuccess` callback. Plaid Link wants me to call `linkHandler.open` with the type of the selected institution passed in, which display Plaid modal dialog that allows the user to enter their credentials and confirm. Then the `onSuccess` callback is called.

But what if I want to let the user enter their user name and password through a custom modal. Is there something like `linkHandler.auth(userName, password)` which would cause `onSuccess` to be called in a similar manner, but without displaying a modal dialog I can't style?

Here's the snippet, but it's basically copy pasted from the docs, so no surprises there:

```
let plaidLink = Plaid.create({
  env: "tartan",
  clientName: "",
  key: "blahblahblah", // A correct public key.
  product: "auth",
  onLoad: () => {
    console.debug("onLoad");
  },
  onSuccess: (publicToken, metadata) => {
    console.debug("onSuccess");
  },
  onExit: () => {
    console.debug("onExit");
  }
});

// Don't want this!
//plaidLink.open("bofa"); 

// Want this, this is cool, but can I get the same for the credential dialog?
console.debug("institutions", plaidLink.institutions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the feature you're looking for does not currently exist in Plaid Link, and likely won't be implemented in the near future. This is because Link was built specifically to handle the rather complicated flow and range of possibilities that each bank has.

For a simple integration like `Wells Fargo`, which requires no MFA question or answer, your proposal would probably work.

```
Plaid.auth('wells', userName, password)
```

But for other institutions like `Chase` and `Bank of America`, which both have a variety of MFA questions, the flow would be much more complex and not possible with one method call.

```
Plaid.auth('chase', userName, password)
Plaid.mfaDevice('chase', device)
Plaid.mfaCode('chase', code)
Plaid.handleMfaError('chase', error)
// ...
```

If you do want to show a custom modal to your users, you can opt to build your own implementation of the Plaid API. Plaid Link however handles all of this complexity for you, and I would highly recommend using it to ensure that your users have a great user-experience. The Plaid team actively maintains Link, so it's continuously improving, along with new features released frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking to rework the current implementation which uses the Plaid API as you suggest. We really want to use Plaid Link in our team so we have decided to drop the custom modal design in favor of being able to integrate it. Thanks for your answer.